Card Stopping Problem - Issue with alternate solution
I'm trying to solve the problem here (Stopping Problem Question) using a similar, but slightly different method from the solution provided.
Here's what I did:
Let $p_B(r,b)$ be the probability that the player wins the game, assuming they just flipped over a black card and $p_R(r,b)$ be the probability that the player wins the game, assuming they just flipped over a red card and that they are using an optimal strategy.

Then we have the following recursions:
$$p_B(b,r)=
\begin{cases}
\text{1 if $r=0$}\\
\text{0 if $b=0$}\\[2pt]
\text{else:}\\
\max\left(
{\displaystyle{\frac{b}{b+r}}},
\;
\left({\displaystyle{\frac{b}{b+r}}}\right)p_B(b-1,r)
+
\left({\displaystyle{\frac{r}{b+r}}}\right)p_R(b,r-1)
\right)
\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$p_R(b,r)=
\begin{cases}
\text{1 if $b=0$}\\
\text{0 if $r=0$}\\[2pt]
\text{else:}\\
\max\left(
{\displaystyle{\frac{r}{b+r}}},
\;
\left({\displaystyle{\frac{b}{b+r}}}\right)p_B(b-1,r)
+
\left({\displaystyle{\frac{r}{b+r}}}\right)p_R(b,r-1)
\right)
\\
\end{cases}
$$
I solve at the end by computing in python:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}P_B(25,26) + \dfrac{1}{2}P_R(26,25)$$
and I get the below, which doesn't match the accepted response. Where is my recursive set-up incorrect?


You wrote that $p_B(b, r) = 0$ if $b = 0$, that is, there is no chance of winning after flipping a black card with $0$ black cards remaining.
But that is not true. If there are at least two red cards remaining, then you are actually guaranteed to win; stop after flipping another card, because that card and the next card are guaranteed to be red.
